# numpy array: IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy

This works:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
>>> a[: , 2]
array([ 3,  7, 11])
```

This doesn't

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11]])
>>> a[:,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Why so ?

Comment: @MatthewCurry That's intentional. Hence the question. Why should that matter ?

Comment: `print(a)` shows that `a` is interpreted differently - the first is a 2D numpy array, the second is a 1D array of three lists `[list([1, 2, 3, 4]) list([5, 6, 7, 8]) list([9, 10, 11])]`.

Comment: Numpy goes for performance, so types must be set. Haven’t used it in awhile, but my guess is that the type of the last array is different: length 3 instead of 4. Numpy can’t make it’s normal assumptions, and so throws an error

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Numpy ndarrays are meant for all elements to have the same length.  In this case, your second array doesn't contain lists of the same length, so it ends up being a 1-D array of lists, as opposed to a "proper" 2-D array.

From the Numpy docs on [N-dimensional arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html):

> An ndarray is a (usually fixed-size) multidimensional container of items of the same type and size.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
a.shape # (3,4)
a.ndim # 2

b = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11]])
b.shape # (3,)
b.ndim # 1
```

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3386428/2799941) may be useful.

Comment: I 'fixed' the length by using `np.pad()` but still I cannot index it. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The first array has shape (3,4) and the second has shape (3,). The second array is missing a second dimension. np.array is unable to use this input to construct a matrix (or array of similarly-lengthed arrays). It is only able to make an array of lists.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])

>>> print(a)
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]]

>>> print(type(a))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>


>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11]])

>>> print(b)
[list([1, 2, 3, 4]) list([5, 6, 7, 8]) list([9, 10, 11])]

>>> print(type(b))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So they are both Numpy arrays, but only the first can be treated as a matrix with two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to see what the problem is.
Try,

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
>>> a.shape
```

and then

```
>>>a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11]])
>>> a.shape
```

and you will see the problem yourself, that in case two, shape is (3,).Hence the too many indices.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error message " IndexError: too many indices for array " but unfortunately I attempted mistake that,
**incorrect syntax:**   LA = np.array( 0 for i in range(20) )

Note: must place **[]** brackets like,
**correct syntax:** LA = np.array ( **[** 0 for i in range(20) **]** )