# 'IndexError: too many indices for array'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to teach myself NumPy in Jupyter Notebooks:

I have an array called 'study_minutes'

But when trying to access using `study_minutes[1, 0]` or `study_minutes[(1, 0)]`, I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0fb6eb80a6ee> in <module>
----> 1 study_minutes[1, 1] = 360

NameError: name 'study_minutes' is not defined
```

The source code from the tutorial I am using gives the same error,

Any idea why guys? I am stumped

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you defining `study_minutes` inside a particular cell, and then calling the array later in the same cell? Jupyter can be a tad tricky for newcomers because the cell run times are all interdependent.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply - I am not sure as literally first day I have used it - I wish there was a way of uploading the Jupyter file (the one from the tutorial) because even that one doesn't seem correct for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure is too many indices error? The last NameError is saying that you did not initialize the array.
 If you still getting the error and you think is due to the too many indices error  [check this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733704/numpy-array-indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array)

Comment: Thank you iLuuPii, I think the array was initialized here: 
`study_minutes = np.zeros(100, np.uint16)`
Does this look correct?
Many thanks

Comment: here's the problem; that's a 1D array but you're calling it as a 2D array.

Comment: This is complete code: Is this still incorrect?

`study_minutes = np.array([
    study_minutes,
    np.zeros(100, np.uint16)
])

study_minutes[1][0] = 60

rand = np.random.RandomState(42)
fake_log = rand.randint(30, 180, size=100, dtype=np.uint16)
fake_log

[fake_log[3], fake_log[8]]

fake_log[[3, 8]]

index = np.array([
    [3, 8],
    [0, 1]
])
fake_log[index]

study_minutes = np.append(study_minutes, [fake_log], axis=0)

study_minutes[1, 1] = 360`

Comment: If you look at your shape by calling `study_minutes.shape` on that initial array, you'll see that you get `(100,)` because of how NumPy is handling the dimensionality internally. If you want to call the index of your 1D array you only need to pass a single variable like `study_minutes[1]` and that'll return a value.

Comment: If you want to instead cast your array to be 2D, you can use a method called "reshape" via something like `np.array([1,2,3]).reshape((1,-1))`, now instead of a 1D shape of `(100,)` NumPy views that as a 2D shape of `(100,1)`

Comment: here's a resource which might help: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.02-the-basics-of-numpy-arrays.html