# How can I do matrix from arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

For example I have:

```
q1=[]
q2=[]
q3=[]
```

And after some operations they are:

```
q1 = [0, 1]
q2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
q3 = [7, 8, 9]
```

So I have 3 arrays. As you see they have different length.
I want to make a `matrix` that will look like:

```
matrix = [[0, 1],
          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]
```

And so for example `matrix[1]` will return `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

**How can I do this?**
I've tried some approaches like `v = np.matrix([q1, q2, q3])` but it doesn't help

Comment: That's not how matrices work. Matrices are rectangular.

Comment: @naivepredictor OK, this is not exactly matrix. I've named it for convenience. But my question is still valid

Comment: All you want is a two-dimension array, but numpy matrix is not for that purpose

Comment: `matrix = [q1,q2,q3]`

Comment: Not a matrix, just a list of lists

Comment: What shape and dtype do you expect?  What's wrong with some of the suggestions?

Comment: The object dtype array will hurt performance.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
q1 = [0, 1]
q2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
q3 = [7, 8, 9]

V = np.array([q1, q2, q3])
print(V[0])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think J. Doe can answer it better. I just followed his pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use numpy here. You can simply create a new list and add q1, q2, and q3 to it.

```
q = [q1, q2, q3]

print(q[1])
```

**Output :**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need `np.matrix` AT ANY PRICE then you could use `np.array` instead, following code:

```
import numpy as np
q1 = [0,1]
q2 = [2,3,4]
x = np.array([q1,q2])
```

I tested it and it works properly in `numpy` version `1.15.4`. However keep in mind that `x` is `array` of `dtype` `object`. For discussion about irregular (non-rectangular/variable-length) arrays see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386259/how-to-make-a-multidimension-numpy-array-with-a-varying-row-size). 
Note also that [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) discourages usage of `np.matrix`.