# How do I delete the end element of a subarray?

Tags: python, numpy, sub-array

So I've created a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I'm trying to delete the end element of this array's subarray:

```
a[0] = (a[0])[:-1]
```

And encounter this issue:

a[0] = (a[0])[:-1]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)

Why can't I change it ?
How do I do it?

Comment: What shape do you want your matrix to end up? (It is `(3, 3)` now.)

Comment: `a=a[:,0:2]` will delete the end of each row. Or you can do `np.delete(a,2,1)`

Comment: I want this shape

Comment: dawg, can you explain how this works please? The first solution

Comment: @grzyb You can delete end of **every** row like dawg says, or for example you can zero the end of the first row, but you must end up with an array of a certain number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

You can do:

```
>>> a[:,0:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Or:

```
>>> np.delete(a,2,1)
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Then in either case, assign that back to `a` since the result is a new array.

So:

```
>>> a=a[:,0:2]
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

If you wanted only to delete `3` in the first row, that is a different problem. You can only do that if you have have an array of python lists since the sublists are not the same length.

Example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a
array([list([1, 2]), list([4, 5, 6]), list([7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

If you do that, just stick to Python. You will have lost all the speed and other advantages of Numpy.

---

If by 'universal' you mean the last element of each row of a N x M array, just use `.shape` to find the dimensions:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 4)
>>> np.delete(a,a.shape[1]-1,1)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Or,

```
>>> a[:,0:a.shape[1]-1]
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, how do I make it universal? How can I get the number of elements of a subarray?

Comment: Define 'universal' in this case? Do you mean given an 2D array `X x Y` dimensions to delete the last element of each row?

Comment: Do you mean given an 2D array X x Y dimensions to delete the last element of each row?
Yes

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> a.shape
(3, 3)
```

The variable `a` is matrix (2D array). It has certain number of rows and columns. In a matrix all the rows must be of same length. As so, in the above example, the matrix cannot be formed if the first row has length 2 and others 3. So deleting the last element of only the first(or any other subset) sub-array is not possible.

Instead you have to delete the last element of all the sub-arrays at the same time.

That can be done as

```
>>> a[:,0:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Or,

```
>>> np.delete(a,2,1)
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

This also applies to the elements of other positions. Deleting can be done of any element of the sub-arrays keeping in mind that all the sub-arrays should have same length.

However you can manipulate the last element(or any other) of any sub-array unless the shape remains constant.

```
>>> a[0][-1] = 19
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2, 19],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

In case you try to form a matrix with rows of unequal length, a 1D array of lists is formed on which no Numpy operations like vector processing, slicing, etc. works (the list operation works)

```
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> c = np.array([[1,2],[1,2,3]])

>>> b
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
>>> b.shape
(2, 3)

>>> c
array([list([1, 2]), list([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
>>> c.shape
(2,)

>>> print(type(b),type(c))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Both are ndarray, but you can see the second variable `c` has is a 1D array of lists.

```
>>> b+b
array([[2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6]])
>>> c+c
array([list([1, 2, 1, 2]), list([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Similarly, `b+b` operation performs the element-wise addition of `b` with `b`, but `c+c` performs the concatenation operation among the two lists.

### For Further Ref

[How to make a multidimension numpy array with a varying row size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386259/how-to-make-a-multidimension-numpy-array-with-a-varying-row-size)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a = a[:-1]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved quite easily with the help of list comprehension:
`[a[0:-1] for a in array]`

For example, there are input data:

Input:

```
array = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9]]


print([a[0:-1] for a in array])
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3],[5,6],[8]]
```

Loop iteration occurs:

```
for a in array
```

In each iteration, `a[0:-1]` is executed and the result is added to a new array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).