# Is numpy optimized to work on array of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Some answers on stackoverflow suggest to use a ndarray of ndarray, when working with data in which the number of elements per row is not constant ([How to make a multidimension numpy array with a varying row size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386259/how-to-make-a-multidimension-numpy-array-with-a-varying-row-size)).

Is numpy optimized to work on a structure like that (array of arrays, also called nested arrays) ?

Here's a simplified example of such a structure:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([4,5])
data = np.array([x,y],dtype=object)
```

It's possible to do operations like:

```
print(data+1)
print(data+data)
```

But some operations would fail like :

```
print(np.sum(data))
```

What's happening behind the scenes with this type of structure ?

Comment: No.  Such an array is basically the same as a list, containing references to the component arrays.

Comment: Check this ;) https://numpy.org/devdocs/dev/internals.html if you want to know more about how the NumPy array is organized in memory.

Comment: My comment is basically a repeat of the accepted answer in your link.  There's a difference between explaining what can be done, and suggesting such a use.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I updated the question to make it more precise.

Comment: What was the `sum` error message?

Comment: Math on such an array is hit or miss.  Typically it iterates through the elements and tries to apply the operator or a method.  But that iteration can easily fail, as in the `np.sum` case, or `np.exp`.  And the speed is basically that of a list comprehension, when it does work.  Compared to an equivalent list, an array can, on occasion, be more convenient, but don't ever assume it is just as good as a numeric array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a list, an object dtype array can contain objects of any kind.  For example

```
In [6]: arr = np.array([1,"two",[1,2,3],np.array([4,5,6])], object)
In [7]: arr
Out[7]: array([1, 'two', list([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Look what happens when we do addition:

```
In [8]: arr+arr
Out[8]: 
array([2, 'twotwo', list([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), array([ 8, 10, 12])],
      dtype=object)
In [10]: arr*2
Out[10]: 
array([2, 'twotwo', list([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), array([ 8, 10, 12])],
      dtype=object)
```

For list and strings, these operations are defined as 'join/replication'.  It's in effect doing `[x.__add__(x) for x in arr]`. where `__add__` is the class specific operation.

`np.exp` doesn't work because it tries to do `[x.exp() for in arr]`, and almost noone defines an `exp` method.

```
In [11]: np.exp(arr)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-16c1c90aa297>", line 1, in <module>
    np.exp(arr)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable exp method
```

Comment: The explanation is super clear. Thanks a lot !